# Mac OS X Lion Installation Issues With Bootcamped Windows 8 Installation

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on my Mac (10.7.5) but I'm running into some big issues. First I'll explain what I already did.

1. Created a partition with the Boot camp assistant (151 GB)  [image: creating a partition in Windows]
2. Installed an **ISO** on my external hard drive.
3. Rebooted my Mac holding the <kbd>⌥option</kbd> key so I could choose a start drive disk
4. Selected **EFI BOOT** [image: Boot selection with Startup Manager]
5. Entered my serial number and continued.

**And here does the trouble begins:**

6. Now a see a list of drivers and my partition but I can't select my `Drive 0 Partition 4: Bootcamp` [image: Selecting a partition to install Windows on]

These are the errors I get:

> "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an
>   MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to
>   GPT disks.
>
> Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be
>   installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.
>
> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is
>   enabled in the computer's BIOS menu"

I already tried to run this command(s)

```
diskpart
select disk 0                      (assuming 0 is the disk where you created the bootcamp partition)
select partition 4                 (assuming 4 is your bootcamp partition)
format fs=NTFS label="Windows 8"   (I didn’t use QUICK)
exit
exit
```

specs: https://gist.github.com/Nathansakoetoe/a733fea6abdc20d47764

**Note: Drive 1 is my external hard disk.**

Comment: Which Mac, which Bootcamp? Win 8 can only be installed with Bootcamp 5 & newer Macs.

Comment: Edited the first message with the specs. I already did installed windows 8 on this mac but the problem was that it only rebooted with my external hard disk connected to it. After that it did not booted again so I had to delete it all.

Answer (score 2):

Superuser [has answer to thi](https://superuser.com/questions/508026/windows-detects-gpt-disk-as-mbr-in-efi-boot)s.

Basically Bootcamp assistant converted the disk from a legal GPT disk into a hybrid MBR disk, which OS X sees as GPT and Windows sees as MBR. The solution in this case is to clear the hybrid MBR data. Check the link to look how to do it.